# What do I need to Use for Drawing Form Like at Picture?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I want to draw form like this (Windows Form or I don't what it is).
[image]
This is "Clock Widget for HTC Home 3".
I know, that this form has drawn (developed, invented :) with Framework 4.
What do I need to use? Maybe Windows Forms, of WPF, or...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF would make it a heck of a lot easier than WinForms.

That said, I'm guessing based on your question that you're going to need more guidance than just being pointed at the "right" technology...